# Numerical Variable in For Loop - Keep Decimals

Tags: for-loop, zsh

Inside a `for-loop`, I have have set some numerical variables with `declare -i`.  However, the numbers keep getting rounded and I need to keep all decimals.  I found a way to keep the desired number of decimals using `awk`, but they disappear when I set the variable with `declare -i` or `export`.

A = the number of rows in the tsv.
B = A / 10

```
for file in *.tsv
do
  declare -i A=$(wc -l < $file) ;
  print $A ;
  declare -i B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}') ;
  print $B ;
done

Terminal output:
2225542
2
```

If I test the code by setting the variables outside of a `for-loop`, I find that the awk command is saving the desired decimals.  They are being lost when the variable is set with `declare -i B=`

```
A=2225542
awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}'

Terminal output:
2.2255420
```

Comment: Please include the she-bang in your script too.

Comment: What is a she-bang?  I have also tried `export` with the same result.  Any way to declare a numerical variable within a loop and keep decimals?

Comment: The she-bang is the first line in a script telling the shell what interpreter to start. `#!/bin/bash` is common for `bash` scripts. `#!/bin/tcsh` for `tcsh` scripts etc.

Comment: At least in `bash`, `declare -i` declares an integer and there is no way to declare a floating point variable. Strings can contain a decimal point though, but you can't use it to do floating point math directly. You'll have to use some external tool, like `bc` or `awk`. So don't do `declare -i B=$(...)`,  just  make it `B=$(...)` to make `B` a string.

Comment: I’m actually copy-pasting this into terminal at the moment, so no she-bang.  That might mean I am using default zsh.  Are you staying I would need to solve and use the variable within the same awk call?

Comment: I see. I had to install `zsh` to get a feeling for it . Turns out, `zsh` does floating point arithmetics out-of-the-box. Very handy :-)

Comment: If you're doing floating point arithmetic in your shell there's an excellent chance you're using the wrong tool. You may want to ask a new question about WHAT you're trying to do rather than this one which is about HOW you're trying to do it (a loop passing values between calls to tools) if you'd like more help.

Comment: No need to post a lot of unrelated code. You can simplify your problem to `declare -i x=8.4; echo $x`, which outputs _8_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `zsh` and `bash`: `wc -l` is going to return an integer so the `declare -i` is not necessary; `A=$(wc -l < $file)` is sufficient.

For `A=2225542` the `awk` script is going to generate a float/real (`2.2255420`).  How the assignment (`declare -i B=$(awk ...)`) is processed will depend on the shell:

Under `zsh` the value is truncated to just the integer portion, eg:

```
$ declare -i B=2.2255420
$ echo $B
2
```

Under `bash` we get an error:

```
$ declare -i B=2.2255420
-bash: declare: 2.2255420: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2255420")
```

`bash` is expecting an integer so it doesn't know what to do when it runs into the `.2255420`.

To have `zsh`, or `bash`, maintain the float/real value (just) remove the `declare -i`, ie:

```
# replace this:

declare -i B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}') 

# with this:

B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}') 

    # or

B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {printf "%.*f\n", length(A), A/1000000}')
```

**NOTES:**

- in reality `bash` doesn't know how to work with float/real values so what you're really storing in `B` is a string
- any attempt to have `bash` process the value in `B` as a float/real will result in either *a)* unexpected results or *b)* and error

Leaving you with:

```
$ echo "$B"
2.2255420
```

Comment: Both `B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}')` and `B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {printf "%.*f\n", length(A), A/1000000}') ` still return 2 on my end.

Comment: @JVGen assuming `A=2225542`, I'm (still) getting `2.2255420` on my system (zsh v 5.8.1, bash v 5.1.16, awk v 5.1.0)

Comment: This worked! I missed that part about not using `declare -i` when setting variable A.  Using `A=$(wc -l < $file)` with your solutions worked.

Comment: @JVGen It doesn't matter if you `declare -i A=$(wc -l < $file)` or remove `declare -i`. Which version of `zsh` are using? Did you try `declare -F B=$((A/1000000.0))`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're declaring `B` to be an integer when you need it to be a floating point variable.

```
declare -F B=$(...)  # B is now a floating point variable
```

You also do not need to involve external commands when doing floating point arithmetics in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) (unlike you do in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for example), but be aware that promotion to floating point doesn't happen automatically. You need one operand to be a floating point. Example:

```
declare -i A=$(wc -l < $file) # A is an integer
declare -F B=A/1000000.0      # B is a float and the division is using floats
print $B                      # prints 2.2255420000
```

Had you divided by `1000000` instead of `1000000.0` the division would have been made using integer values and the result would be `2` that would then be assigned to the floating point variable `B` and `print $B` would then have printed `2.0000000000`.

---

In older [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)s you may need to do the division like this:

```
declare -F B=$((A/1000000.0))
```

However, prior to version 4.0.1 (released 22 years ago), you probably can't do the floating point arithmetics directly at all, but need to revert to using plain strings and external tools like [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to do the calculations.

Comment: swapping out line `declare -i B=$(awk -v A=$A 'BEGIN {d=length(A); printf "%."d"f\n", A/1000000}')` for `declare -F B=A/1000000.0 ` returns `zsh: bad assignment` when I run the code.

Comment: @JVGen You must use a very old zsh version (< 4.0.1 I think). What does `zsh --version` return? What if you use `declare -F B=$((A/1000000.0))` instead?

Comment: `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)` Is this outdated?    Yes, `declare -F B=$((A/1000000.0))` keeps the decimal places.  Thank you!

Comment: @JVGen No, 5.9 is even newer than my version (5.8.1) :-) I find it odd that my original suggestion doesn't work. Mind to check this again: `declare -i A=123` `declare -F B=A/10.` `print $B` - For me that prints `12.3000000000`

Comment: Your original version works now.  It must have been a mistake in my code structure (like a missing `;` or something).  Sorry about that.

Comment: @JVGen No worries! I'm glad that was cleared up, so thanks for testing it again.

Comment: Hey @Ted Lyngmo, I recently tried running this code by saving it as a .sh file and calling it in terminal (zsh).  The print functions throw and error.  However, if I run the same code by directly typing in terminal, it runs without error.  Any ideas why this happens?  TYIA

Comment: @JVGen You should **always declare** what interpreter you want your scripts to use to not get a "random" one. `(echo '"!'$(which zsh); cat yout_current_script_file) > new_script_file`

Comment: @JVGen The first line in `new_script_file` is called a "shebang" and declares what interpreter to use. Your question was about how to do this in `zsh` and my answer is written using `zsh` syntax. The shebang in `new_script_file` makes that work.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  So I would just add #! /bin/zsh as the first line of the script file?  I’ll give it a go tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: @JVGen Yes, that's it. You'll see a shebang in most scripts. `#!/bin/python`  makes it run the script using the python interpreter for example.

Comment: Even after adding `#!/bin/zsh` as the first line in my `.sh` file, when I run the script through terminal with `sh myscript.sh`, I get an error: `print: command not found`.  Strange because if I copy-paste the code directly into terminal the print command runs as expected.

Comment: @JVGen Why running it with `sh` first, you are telling the shell to _ignore_ the interpretator specified in the shebang and instead use `sh` (which is usually `bash` nowadays). Bash and Zsh are different scripting languages. Just make the script executable (`chmod +x myscript.sh`) and then run it without `sh` like so `./myscript.sh`

Comment: Doh!  Never knew that I could call a script without sh.  Thanks - it’s working now